# Какого рода слово "мужчина"?

Tags: словообразование

Казалось бы, глупый вопрос. Но в русском языке есть тенденция, согласно которой признаком женского рода является окончание "-а" (не обязательно, конечно, но часто): кот - кошка, голубь - голубка, имена: Иван - Иванна, Олег - Ольга, Александр - Александра и т.д., причем женский род образуется от мужского путем добавления этого окончания. 
Но из этого ряда выбивается пара "женщина - мужчина". Почему в этой паре оба слова оканчиваются на "а", вызывая ассоциации с женским родом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В русском языке к 1-му скл. с окончанием А в начальной форме относится целый ряд преимущественно одушевленных существительных мужского рода:

а) юноша, вельможа (велЪ + можа), старшина, детина, дядя, папа;

б) также слова с суффиксами субъективной оценки: старикашка, мальчишка, волчишка, человечишка.

Образование существительных мужчина и женщина относят к 14-16 веку, они мотивированы словами муж и жена. Образование шло о схеме: муж - мужской - мужчина, жена - женский - женщина. Таким образом, мужчина - это дословно носитель мужских качеств.

Answer (score 1):

Слова мужчина, женщина появились около XIII - XV веке, когда стали применять уничижительные *щина* и *чина* - деревенщина, военщина и т.п.  Таким путем из слова *муж* получилось *мужчина* и из *жена* - *женщина*.  см. В.В. Виноградов "История слов" Мужчина, Женщина.